# Is NSNumberFormatter the only way to format an NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm using an NSDecimalNumber to store money in Core Data. I naively used stringWithFormat: at first to format the value, later realizing that it didn't support NSDecimalNumber and was instead formatting the pointer :(. So after some reading through the docs I learned to use the NSNumberFormatter to get the format I wanted. But this just strikes me as the "hard way". Is there any easier way than this:?

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
priceField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: ent.price];
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that approach, and it's the conventional pattern to convert opaque number classes to strings.

If I have a `UIView` that uses a formatter often, I'll usually have one as an instance member so I avoid having to repeatedly `alloc`/`init`/`release` the formatter.

Answer (score 18):

on iOS 4.0 and later you can use this method:

```
NSString* currencyString = [NSNumberFormatter 
                                 localizedStringFromNumber:number
                                 numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSNumberFormatter can be expensive, why not just call [ent descriptionWithLocale:]

Comment: From what I can tell in the docs, that doesn't provide a way to format currency.

Answer (score -1):

Just convert it to a double and use "F"

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2F", [ent doubleValue]];

Comment: It's certainly quicker, but I believe there are cases where this will display the wrong value. If one could just use doubles everywhere, you wouldn't need NSDecimalNumber in the first place.