# How to divide NSDecimalNumber by integer?

Tags: ios, cocoa

I don't think a comprehensive, basic answer to this exists here yet, and googling didn't help.

**Task**: Given an `NSDecimalNumber` divide this by an `int` and return another `NSDecimalNumber`.
**Clarification**: `amount_text` below must be converted to a NSDecimalNumber because it is a currency. The result must be a NSDecimalNumber, but I don't care what format the divisor is.

What I have so far:

```
// Inputs
NSString *amount_text = @"15.3";
int n = 10;

NSDecimalNumber *total = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amount_text]; 

// Take int, convert to string. Take string, convert  to NSDecimalNumber.
NSString *int_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", n];
NSDecimalNumber *divisor = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:int_string];
NSDecimalNumber *contribution = [total decimalNumberByDividingBy:divisor];
```

Surely, this can be done in a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you're using `NSDecimalNumber`? This can be done way easier like this:

```
// Inputs
NSString *amount_text = @"15.3";
int n = 10;

float amount = [amount_text floatValue];
float result = amount / n;
```

If you really want to do it with `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
// Inputs
NSString *amount_text = @"15.3";
int n = 10;

NSDecimalNumber *total = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amount_text];
NSDecimalNumber *divisor = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:n exponent:0 isNegative:NO];
NSDecimalNumber *contribution = [total decimalNumberByDividingBy:divisor];
```

Comment: I am using NSDecimalNumber because I am dealing with currencies. But your alternative works.

Comment: If you need high precision for your values, that would also be a reason to use NSDecimalNumber

Answer (score 4):

You can always use initialisers when creating NSDecimalNumber. Since it is a subclass of NSNumber, NSDecimalNumber overrides initialisers.

So you can do

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:10];
```

however, you should be careful if your are doing high precision calculations as there are some problems using these initialisers. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304855/proper-way-to-instantiate-an-nsdecimalnumber-from-float-or-double) in more detail.

Comment: Which one is better:  Your solution or DrummerB's (second) solution? Let's say my decimalNumber/divisor is between 1 and 10.

Comment: Given the discussion in the linked question you should probably go with DrummerB's second solution `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:n exponent:0 isNegative:NO];`

Comment: You get more precision with DrummerB's second solution, but you should be okay with inits as well. So it's up to you to decide, if you need more precision or not

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (potentially losing some precision):

```
double amount = 15.3;
double n = 10.0;
double contribution = amount / n;

// conversion to decimal
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", n];
NSDecimalNumber *contribution_dec = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string];
```

better yet (if n=10):

```
[dec decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:-1];
```

Comment: Clarified my question: I need NSDecimalNumber. Great thinking with `decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10` however I will have non-power of 10 divisors mostly.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code...

You are creating an `NSDecimalNumber` from string and then doing manipulations with it.

I never do that. Unless you need NSDecimalNumber unless you want a boxed Objective-C Object, Avoid it, use float and double.

---

If you want to do it much simpler you can do it as:

```
float quotient = [total floatValue]/n;
```

or,

```
float quotient = [contribution floatValue]/n;
```

**EDIT**: If you want with any specific reason to use boxed type then you can use as:

```
NSString *amount_text = @"15.3";
int n = 10;

NSDecimalNumber *total = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amount_text];
NSDecimalNumber *divisor = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:n];
NSDecimalNumber *contribution = [total decimalNumberByDividingBy:divisor];
```

Comment: Clarification: I need to use NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: Can I know the reason for that? as you are converting string to int, then decimal number again back to float/int and string... why this overhead? Anyways updated my answer to give you boxed type

Comment: I am having a user type in an amount using the numpad-keyboard. This I convert to `NSDecimalNumber total`, which I also need somewhere else. Here, I want to split the amount among n items.