# Understanding NSDecimalRound Behaviour

Tags: swift, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to round down `Decimal` values using `NSDecimalRound(...`. For the most part it's behaving according to my expectations, but now and again it returns a value that takes me by surprise. In the example below the first calculation does what I would expect, that is, with a `scale` of `4`, rounds `2341.2143` down to `2341.2143` (i.e. the same value). The second calculation is identical except that the value being rounded now is `2341.2142` (note last digit is 2 not 3), this time the returned value is `2341.2141` whereas I would expect a value of `2341.2142`. Similar behaviour is found with `2341.2146`, which becomes `2341.2145` when rounded down to 4 d.p. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
// Working as expected... ////////////
var unrounded: Decimal = 2341.2143
var rounded = Decimal()

NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &unrounded, 4, .down)
print(rounded) // 2.2143

// A bit unexpected (to me at least) /////////
var unrounded: Decimal = 2341.2142
var rounded = Decimal()

NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &unrounded, 4, .down)
print(rounded) // 2.2141
```

Comment: I've not come across any documentation warning me to avoid doing this. It's not illogical is it? I mean it's clearly a bit pointless, but there is a right answer isn't there, so it seems reasonable to expect to get it. This code will be used in a function that gets two decimals and rounds the second to match the scale of the first. If I have to then I can add a check to make sure I don't end up in this position, I'd just rather not have to.

Comment: @PaulPatterson If you need to preserve the fraction precision you need to use Decimal string initializer. `Decimal(string: "2341.2142")!` or `Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -4, significand: 23412142)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the [literal](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID414) which is `Double` and which has to be converted to a `Decimal`.  So the error comes from the conversion:

```
var unrounded: Decimal = 2341.2143
//   ^-- decimal var    ^-- Double literal
```

As you know, the floating point encoding is error prone. You can [check here](https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point) that:

```
2341.2143 is encoded as 2341.21430000000009385985322296619415283203125  
     rounded down makes 2341.2143
2341.2142 is encoded as 2341.21419999999989158823154866695404052734375 
     rounded down makes 2341.2141
```

You need to [initialize the `Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) to benefit from the superior precision. Unfortunately, this is not intuitive. You can for example use, the following, which behaves as expected:

```
var unrounded3: Decimal = Decimal(sign:.plus, exponent:-4, significand:23412142)
var rounded3 = Decimal()
NSDecimalRound(&rounded3, &unrounded3, 4, .down)
print(rounded3)
```

Comment: Ok, so actually the same mistake discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453691/how-to-use-nsdecimalnumber

Comment: Or here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304855/proper-way-to-instantiate-an-nsdecimalnumber-from-float-or-double

Comment: @matt thanks for these complementary references. It seems the same problem.  But the code snippets there are Objective-C, which is less telling to people who started directly with Swift.  Moreover, one could have expected that in the 7 to 11 years after these answers, now that Decimal became a first class Swift type, that there would be some better support (it would not be difficult for the compiler to add a suffix to the litteral for parsing directly Decimals).

Comment: On the contrary, it remains full of traps and bugs.