# How to convert NSDecimal to NSString with custom format

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How can I show NSDecimal with custom format? Something like "%.2f" or "%.4f". NSDecimalString just throws away zeroes (e.g 4.10 becomes 4.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:myDecimal] doubleValue]]
```

Alternatively, look into [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks. How does this insane converting NSDecimal->NSDecimalNumber->float->NSString affect performance?

Comment: Well, it's certainly non-optimal! Whether that matters depends on how often you have to call it.

Comment: There's no need to pass through `float`. Does that not kind of defeat using `NSDecimalNumber` in the first place?  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8683163/111307)